# An error is reported when the HMS is used to send Urban Airship push notifications

Tags: urbanairship.com, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

An error occurs when I attempt to send an urban airship push notification through the HMS. The following message is displayed: UALib: PushManager - Push registration failed with error: HMS error Empty HMS registration token. Will retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After configuring applications in the application library, you can enable the Push Kit by following the instructions in the following link and perform all the initial integration required by the Push Kit through the HMS. Link address: [https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/tree/master/urbanairship-hms。](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/tree/master/urbanairship-hms%E3%80%82)